# Asynchronous server stopping getting data from client with no visible reason

Tags: c++, boost, asynchronous, client-server, boost-asio

I have a problem with client-server application. As I've almost run out of sane ideas for its solving I am asking for help. I've stumbled into described situation about three or four times now. Provided data is from last failure, when I've turned all the possible logging, messages dumping and so on.

**System description**
1) *Client.* Works under Windows. I take as an assumption that there is no problem with its work (judging from logs)
2) *Server.* Works under Linux (RHEL 5). It is server where I has a problem.
3) *Two connections* are maintained between client and server: one command and one for data sending. Both work asynchronously. Both connections live in one thread and on one `boost::asio::io_service`.
4) *Data to be sent* from client to server is messages delimeted by '\0'.
5) *Data load* is about 50 Mb/hour, 24 hours a day.
6) Data is read on server side using `boost::asio::async_read_until` with corresponding delimeter

**Problem**
- For two days system worked as expected
- On third day at `18:55` server read one last message from client and then stopped reading them. No info in logs about new data.
- From `18:55` to `09:00` (14 hours) client reported no errors. So it sent data (about 700 Mb) successfully and no errors arose.
- At `08:30` I started investigation of a problem. Server process was alive, both connections between server and client were alive too.
- At `09:00` I attached to server process with `gdb`. Server was in sleeping state, waiting for some signal from system. I believe I accidentally hit Ctrl + C and may be there was some message.
- Later in logs I found message with smth like 'system call interrupted'. After that both connections to client were dropped. Client reconnected and server started to worked normally.
- The first message processed by server was timestamped at `18:57` on client side. So after restarting normal work, server didn't drop all the messages up to `09:00`, they were stored somewhere and it processed them accordingly after that.

**Things I've tried**
- Simulated scenario above. As server dumped all incoming messages I've wrote a small script which presented itself as client and sent all the messages back to server again. Server dropped with `out of memory` error, but, unfortunately, it was because of high data load (about 3 Gb/hour this time), not because of the same error. As it was Friday evening I had no time to correctly repeat the experiment.
- Nevertheless, I've run server through Valgrind to detect possible memory leaks. Nothing serious was found (except the fact that server was dropped because of high load), no huge memory leaks.

**Questions**
- Where were these 700 Mb of data which client sent and server didn't get? Why they were persistent and weren't lost when server restarted the connection?
- It seems to me that problem is someway connected with server not getting message from `boost::asio::io_service`. Buffer is get filled with data, but no calls to read handler are made. Could this be problem on OS side? Something wrong with asynchronous calls may be? If it is so, how could this be checked?
- What can I do to detect the source of problem? As i said I've run out of sane ideas and each experiment costs very much in terms of time (it takes about two or three days to get the system to described state), so I need to run as much possible checks for experiment as I could.

Would be grateful for any ideas I can use to get to the error.

**Update:** Ok, it seems that error was in synchronous `write` left in the middle of asynchronous client-server interaction. As both connections lived in one thread, this synchronous `write` was blocking thread for some reason and all interaction both on command and data connection stopped. So, I changed it to async version and now it seems to work.

Comment: Interesting. Get back with more info when you start working on it on monday :)

Comment: Also have you checked for packet drops, tcp buffer queue size growth ? It would be better if you track them when you test it again

Comment: @ArunMu As i've got almost no ideas at the moment it would be a bit difficult to get more sensible info. No I haven't checked for packet drops/tcp buffer queue size growth. Can I monitor it with some system tools, or should I check it someway in the code?

Comment: Check the netstat options. for unix it is "netstat -S". for linux its some other option and you can also check the proc filesyatem for tcp parameters

Answer (score 0):

> As i said I've run out of sane ideas and each experiment costs very
>   much in terms of time (it takes about two or three days to get the
>   system to described state)

One way to simplify investigation of this problem is to run server inside some [Virtual Machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine) until it reaches this broken state. Then you can make [snapshot](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1009402) of whole system and revert to it every time when things go wrong during investigation. At least you will not have to wait 3 days to get this state again.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It would indeed help to investigate system at broken state. Don't know how it would capture i/o state of the system though. If I won't find solution in couple of days, I'll definitely go to VMWare.